# impossible to extract data from scalar / JSONB

Tags: sql, postgresql, crystal-lang

I seem to have an issue with the column "data" in my table "commercial_action_agreements".
It is supposedly a JSONB type.

```
=# \d+ commercial_action_agreements

        Column        |           Type           |
----------------------+--------------------------+
 data                 | jsonb                    |
```

It looks odd though, since it is marked in quotes instead of having its key and value in quotes:

```
=# SELECT data FROM commercial_action_agreements;
            data        
    --------------------
     "{tire_count: 3}"
     "{tire_count: 3}"
     "{tire_count: 34}"
     "{tire_count: 50}"
     "{tire_count: 47}"
     "{tire_count: 45}"
     "{tire_count: 15}"
     "{tire_count: 28}"
     "{tire_count: 30}"
     "{tire_count: 3}"
     "{tire_count: 3}"
     "{tire_count: 3}"
    (12 rows)
```

It is "{tire_count: 3}" instead of {"tire_count": 3} or {"tire_count": "3"}

If I try to extract the value of 'tire_count' I get null values:

```
=# SELECT data -> 'tire_count' AS tire_count FROM commercial_action_agreements;
     tire_count 
    ------------
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
    (12 rows)
    
=# SELECT data -> 'tire_count' AS tire_count FROM commercial_action_agreements WHERE data->'tire_count' IS NOT NULL;

 tire_count 
------------
(0 rows)
```

and if I try to extract the keys, I find out this is a scalar (which as a SQL newbie I don't know and can't seem to understand what it means):

```
=# SELECT DISTINCT jsonb_object_keys(data::JSONB) FROM commercial_action_agreements;
ERROR:  cannot call jsonb_object_keys on a scalar
```

This JSONB will have more than one key/value pair, so quick and dirty solutions like cutting the substring "tire_count: " are not an option.

I don't know why every instance of "data" is a scalar and if it being a scalar constitutes a problem in itself.
The data is created and (normally) accessed through a Crystal/Lucky API and requests in postman, so I think the whole "data being a scalar" issue might be something caused by something in the serializer, but that is not (I believe) the core of this issue.

I wish to find a way to extract keys and values from this JSONB.

Comment: That is exactly the core of this issue.  The content of that column is nothing more than a JSON string (scalar).  It is not an object, so you cannot treat it like one.  You need to fix whatever is inserting that value because it is doing it wrong.  When you select on that column you need to be seeing something like: `{"tire_count": 47}`

Comment: Thank you for the useful, clear explanation on scalars. You really must be right. For some reputation-related reason I can't seem to be able to upvote your reply :(